# How to add a iOS Device to use it as a test device

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, testing

I am trying to test my application on a test device. 
I added my device in the members portal and als made a provision profile. 
When I add this provisioning profile to my device in the xcode organiser It keeps saying this

```
Valid signing identity not found
```

I think there is something wrong with my keychain. I've added my developer certificate to the keychain. But do I need also something else? My certificate also doesn't show up in the keys part of my keyhain.

Kind regards.

[Here you can see a screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74322780@N08/8079286537/in/photostream)

Comment: Have you completed all the steps in the Provisioning Portal? There is a Launch Assistant taking you through all the steps required for your App. Also have you created and uploaded your Certificate?

Comment: did you download .mobileprovision file

Comment: @CodersParadise Where can I find that mobileprovision file?

Comment: @dngfng I completed all the steps. But my certificate doesn't shows up in my keys in the keyschain. Like you can see over here http://mobiforge.com/files/iphone-real-21.jpg

Comment: file should appear in Provisioning > Distribution > profile that you created. If you completed other steps it should appear.

Comment: mm it doesn't appear in the distribution. But it does show up in development. I don't want to ditribute it yet, I only want to test it on a device.

Comment: It may just be coincidental but the first time I did this, I restarted XCode and it worked...

Comment: then try to download it and drag and drop it to xcode. Then try to run it again

Comment: I restarted xcode but no effect. I also drag and dropped it into xcode but also no change.